# How to make a query for group by count in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I looking for information by event_id 2771

And i get result table (example):
[image: result table]

I want to group the data and hide the duplicate TargetUser by their count in table. I want this result:
[image: wanted result]

Is it possible?
How to make a query for group by count?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested aggregations to do that, like this query:

```
{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" :{
        "event_id":{
            "terms: {
                "field": "event_id"
            },
            "aggs":{
                "TargetUser":{
                    "terms":{
                        "field": "TargetUser"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "ipAddress": {
                            "terms":{
                                "field": "ipAddress"
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```